# Please add TeX rendering on the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, mathjax

MathJax isn't currently working on the Android app, which makes it totally useless for the 'technical' sites like [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

---

For example, in the Android app:

> [image]

Same post in a (mobile) browser:

> [image]

---

#### Please add this functionality!

Comment: @JoshMein I added screenshots, thought they can explain what I'm talking about.

Comment: MathJax is a massive dependency - truly not something you want to download and execute on most mobile calls. Not sure what the plan for these is, but I doubt that MathJax is it. TeX is TeX - doesn't **require** MathJax.

Comment: How about shipping MathJax with the app and loading it from its assets? I'm doing it in my application, and it works fine

Comment: Just some related reading for those interested: [Nick did some performance testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203977/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on/204003#204003) (for the regular sites).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Update 2/18/14:

MathJax is enabled in application as of version 1.0.13, coming out later tonight. It's only supported in a limited selection of places:

1. Question and answer contents
2. Comments, accessible via a tap --> <kbd>Render Mathjax</kbd>

MathJax is *not* rendered in question titles anywhere. That means in the feed, search results, and even when looking at an individual question.

[image]

---

Original answer:

This is something we've talked about a bit before and decided to delay figuring out what to actually do until after our initial release.

To give more explanation here:

- Adding MathJax / LaTeX to question and answer bodies is really easy. It consists of just putting their javascript in the app and using it the same way we're using prettify.js in the app.
- Adding it to comments is troublesome.
- Adding it to question titles is troublesome.
- Adding it to the question listings is troublesome.

Since everything in the app other than the question/answer bodies are native code rather than webviews, this is going to take us a while to try and figure out. At the moment we're putting it on the backburner.

Comment: I have the same issue in Electrical Engineering. Choosing 'render Mathjax' does not work. See the full question an report here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244860/android-app-doesnt-render-latex-content-in-comments?noredirect=1#comment802040_244860

Comment: Is there any update on this? This is a rather annoying issues sometimes.