# LaTex Editor for the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

There is no easy way to type LaTeX through the Stack Exchange app. And in many cases, like Mathematics Stack Exchange, typing LaTeX is almost indispensable. So I think the Android app should provide a keyboard tailored for entering LaTeX.

Comment: Some of the suggestions [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/physics-math-keyboard-for-android-app.765829/) may help, I didn't review them thoroughly though. There's also [a few other possible hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+latex+keyboard).

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't ideal. I would prefer a more graphical approach - press the integtal button to get a integral - - a WYSIWYG editor

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217877/230261 as a starting point, see links in posts, comments, and answers for potential other options.