# MathJax borks in titles in Android app

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app, mathjax

See this screenshot:

> [image]

MathJax is now enabled for the Android app (yay!). However, it doesn't work in titles.

Could this be fixified?

Comment: It was explained in the post where it was status-completed that MathJax wasn't in titles, possibly a dupe?

Comment: I think the right way to fix this is to disable MathJaX rendering in titles on the sites as well. (It should be possible to exclude a particular html element from rendering). Then the users will finally have an incentive to come up with titles that can actually be used for searching.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 Some sites like Math.SE use MathJax so heavily in titles that it is pretty much impossible to switch it off there now. Other sites like Biology or Chemistry already try to avoid putting MathJax into titles even though it works due to the issues with the hot questions list, the appearance in search results and the performance/latency issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in my [meta post announcing the addition of MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213825/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-android-app/214264#214264) this is a known issue. However, it's really unlikely for this to be resolved since it means turning *everything* in the application to `WebView`s rather than just question and answer bodies.

Comment: I've been meaning to ask how you did this. So did you turn the bodies to WebViews pointing toward the specific question or answer? Or did you create a WebView from the body returned from the API?

Comment: From day 0 the actual contents of a question and answer have been customized `WebView`s. We simply get the HTML from the API and stick it into those. The customization aspect came it when we added the same syntax highlighting (prettify.js) and now the same LaTeX rendering (MathJax)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256480/easier-mechanism-to-display-mathjax-in-comments