# Please add TeX rendering in titles on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, mathjax

TeX support works fine in question and answer bodies, and comments can be rendered manually by tapping and selecting Render MathJax. See related question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222868/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-ios-app).

However, the titles are not rendered which makes the browsing experience less than perfect. See screenshot below.

Are there any plans to implement MathJax support in titles?

(I'm running Stack Exhange iOS App Version 1.0.0 on an iPhone 4S with iOS 7.1.1)

---

EDIT: I was just informed about [this declined request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221927/mathjax-borks-in-titles-in-android-app) asking for the same functionality for the Android app. I guess I shouldn't hope too much then...

[image]

Comment: Same problem occurs in comments.

Comment: @WChargin Not quite, you can tap a comment and choose Render MathJax. But I guess it is related in that a direct render of comments would require the same technology as rendering titles.