# Please add TeX rendering on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, mathjax, latex

This is the iOS call for TeX support analogous to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213825/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-android-app) for Android.

That really says it all, but in case you need convincing that many posts on [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) and [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com) are nearly unreadable without rendering TeX, I present screenshots of the sixth highest voted answer on Physics.

[image: app version]

Above is the iOS app, v 0.1.20. Below is the same page on mobile Safari.

[image: browser version]

Whether it's done through MathJax or some other interpreting, TeX really needs to be incorporated in order for the app to be worth using at all on sites that employ it.

Comment: Mathjax works by JavaScript. Is the iOS app using WebKit to render?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Support for TeX has been added** for questions and answers.

Also, if a comment contains TeX in it, tapping it will display an option that allows you to see the comment with the TeX rendered.

This will be **available in version  0.1.30**