# Can the iOS app support manually loaded MathJax extensions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, mathjax

[LaTeX-style formatting works very well now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222868/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-ios-app) on the app, thank you. But today I noticed that the app does not seem to play well with MathJax extensions loaded by the poster. For example, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116514/simplifying-a-seemingly-simple-gamma-matrix-identity) on Physics.SE has the command `\require{cancel}` inside one of the equations. On mobile Safari, this renders fine:

[image: browser screenshot]

But on the app, the `\cancel{}` commands do not work:

[image: app screenshot]

Can the app get the same full MathJax support as the main site and the mobile version of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug report revealed that we were missing a few important MathJax extensions in our app.

This will be fixed in the next app update, probably **version 1.0.2**.