# Viewing LaTeX in comments on the iOS app

Tags: support, comments, ios-app, mathjax

Is there any way to view LaTeX/MathJax in comments on the iOS app? It makes reading comments almost impossible, especially on MSE or MO.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 11.0.3 (Build 15A432)

Comment: For instance, all of the comments on this page: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470986/type-theory-vs-higher-order-logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accordind to 3 years old [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227100/339911) for iOS-app rendering in comments is available via "Render MathJax" button after tapping a comment:

> [image: Render MayhJax]

Using this button will render comment in the separate page:

> [image: rendered]