# MathJax disabled in comments on android

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

[image]

As you can see above, It does not appear to be enabled in the comments.

Android app version: 1.0.57 

Android version: 4.1.2

Comment: It seems to work fine in regular posts though

Comment: This is by design: to render MathJax in a comment, one has to [tap some option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213825/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-android-app/214264#214264)

Comment: Ok, did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, you can tap on a comment to view the MathJax rendering. We should definitely get better at explaining this, however.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256480/easier-mechanism-to-display-mathjax-in-comments

Comment: This is in the six-to-eight-months regime rather than the weeks now, but it's [still causing confusion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/cannot-view-latex-on-the-comments-section-and-the-title-in-the-stack-exchange-ap). I don't use the app but it definitely sounds like you could still (and should pronto) get better at explaining this behaviour.

Comment: I'd love to hear the explanation for this