# MathJax doesn't work in comments and title of questions in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mathjax

I use my smartphone to access this site through the Stack Exchange Android app. As the title of question suggests, I am unable to see mathematical expressions in comments and the title of questions rendered in [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax).

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251316/mathjax-disabled-in-comments-on-android/251465#251465)