# Displaying LaTeX in comments

Tags: feature-request, android-app, latex

Would it be possible to display Latex in comments.  Yesterday I posted a math question, which someone helpfully edited. They changed all occurrences of a^b to a<sup>b</sup>. Like two squared can be written 2 * 2 = 2^2 or 2<sup>2</sup>.

This resulted in answers being posted containing LaTeX which the app doesn't format leaving what look like a combination of spurious characters scattered through your math formula.

If you can format LaTeX in questions, answers and comments on the full Web site. You can format LaTeX in app questions. Why not app comments.

On an aside what's the Web address for the SE mobile site. My search engine only finds links for app download and links to the main site.

Comment: You need to tap the comment and choose "Render MathJax" as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213825/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-android-app).

Answer (score 3):

If you have version 1.0.13 or later of the Android app, you can tap on a comment and select Render MathJax to render any MathJax within the comment.

> MathJax is enabled in application as of version 1.0.13, coming out later tonight. It's only supported in a limited selection of places:
>
> 1. Question and answer contents
> 2. Comments, accessible via a tap --> <kbd>Render Mathjax</kbd>

<sup>Source: [Please add TeX rendering on the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213825/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-android-app)</sup>

The [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) version of Stack Exchange is accessible when viewing the full site from a mobile device. You can select ‘mobile’ in the footer should you not be presented with the mobile layout automatically.

[image]