# Latex not rendering in answers and questions on Android app for tablet

Tags: support, android-app, latex, android-tablet-app

I have version 1.085 of the app, but latex is not displayed correctly (not even in the answer section). [image]
[image]

Comment: You're talking about [this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213825/158100), right? Can you maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: I added some screenshots

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: The device is Acer Iconia Tab A101

Comment: So a tablet. Not sure it's a bug, the app for tablet is different, created after the original android app, and probably still lacking some features.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. I will wait then. Thank you!